# Why can't Let's Encrypt support wildcard certificates?

Tags: certificates, certificate-authority, letsencrypt, wildcard

Let's Encrypt [claims](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/faq/):

> We do not offer Organization Validation (OV), Extended Validation (EV), or **wildcard certificates**, primarily **because we cannot automate issuance** for those types of certificates.

To be honest, I... don't believe them. Why exactly should this be the case?

Comment: With LetsEncrypt being so easy to use and automate, what is the need for wildcard certificates?

Comment: @korockinout13: I'm not here to argue about the uses of wildcard certificates or lack thereof, but if there was no use it wouldn't be an FAQ on the users' part.

Comment: I think your emphasis distorts the meaning. The sentence claims they do not offer three types of certificates. Then explains that the primary reason (hence not the only one) is lack of automation. It doesn't say that they do not offer each type for the same and single reason. The reason might be very different for the wildcard certificates, yet the sentence is logically coherent because of the word "primarily", if it was the reason for OV and EV certificates.

Comment: You stated, _To be honest, I... don't believe them._ If you don't believe them for that, why would you believe them to issue you a certificate at all? The whole certificate system is based on _trust_, and if you don't trust someone in the chain you can't trust anything in _any_ chain that relies upon the untrusted entity.

Comment: @GypsySpellweaver: Trust is a funny thing. *I* don't need to trust them for them to issue *me* a certificate. *Other* people do. And in any case, it's possible to trust a person regarding X but not Y. Case in point, just because I trust that you'll write in complete sentences that doesn't imply I have to somehow trust that your arguments will make sense.

Comment: @Mehrdad accepted. :) I do hope that you've since availed yourself of LE's system to get the wildcard certs you needed. Or, found a suitable alternative source.

Comment: They now support wildcard certificates: https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/acme-v2-and-wildcard-certificate-support-is-live/55579

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Let's Encrypt just announced that they will offer wildcard certificates in 2018:

> Wildcard certificates will be offered free of charge via our upcoming ACME v2 API endpoint. We will initially only support base domain validation via DNS for wildcard certificates, but may explore additional validation options over time. We encourage people to ask any questions they might have about wildcard certificate support on our [community forums](https://community.letsencrypt.org/).

Source: https://letsencrypt.org/2017/07/06/wildcard-certificates-coming-jan-2018.html

**Wildcard support support is now live** as of 2018/03/13! Link for steps necessary https://community.letsencrypt.org/t/acme-v2-production-environment-wildcards/55578

Comment: Thank you for the update. I have not been monitoring the LE website, and didn't even notice the [ACME v2 announcement](https://letsencrypt.org/2017/06/14/acme-v2-api.html) made mid-June. Having that new standard, which allows LE to do wildcard certs is wonderful.

Comment: @costrouc, nice to see that you updated this answer, and also nice to see wildcard support from letsencrypt. : )

Answer (score 21):

**As a result of an [announcement](https://letsencrypt.org/2017/07/06/wildcard-certificates-coming-jan-2018.html) by [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org), the information in this answer is now of historical value only.** See the information in [Emil Stenström](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/6182)'s [answer](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/163537/135823).

The IETF-standardized ACME v2 protocol will be available soon, and [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org) [announced on 14 June, 2017](https://letsencrypt.org/2017/06/14/acme-v2-api.html) that they will have a new API endpoint against that standard in Jan. 2018. As reported by [Emil](https://security.stackexchange.com/users/6182) in his answer, [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org) announce today (6 June, 2017) that they will be able to use the new API endpoint to issues the much demanded wildcard certificates. *Good catch Emil.*

---

After a, too long, exchange in comments, I've decided to collect, and expand, them into an answer. Hopefully this will help. I'm avoiding any discussion of the OV and EV certs because they have a whole different scenario, and the title of the question clearly asks
*Why can't Let's Encrypt support* wildcard *certificates?*

Top of the list of "why" is that the [ACME](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Automated_Certificate_Management_Environment) protocol, which is the foundation of LE's validation, does not yet cover wildcard validation. Without that in place LE simply cannot issue such certs, whether they want to or not. However, there has been discussion on the [IETF ACME mailing list](https://mailarchive.ietf.org/arch/search/?email_list=acme&q=wildcard), so there may yet be hope for inclusion in the protocol at least. Also, the LE [FAQ](https://letsencrypt.org/docs/faq/#will-lets-encrypt-issue-wildcard-certificates) further explains that wildcard certs are not indefinitely ruled out. Though they may reach that status eventually anyway.

> **Will Let’s Encrypt issue wildcard certificates?**
>
> We currently have no plans to do so, but it is a possibility in the future. Hopefully wildcards aren't necessary for the vast majority of our potential subscribers because it should be easy to get and manage certificates for all subdomains.

Automation of the issuance process is a **[key principle](https://letsencrypt.org/about/)** behind Let's Encrypt. So, anything that cannot be automated will *not* happen through them. That is one point they have repeatedly stressed in postings on their [community forum](https://community.letsencrypt.org/).

Part of the problem with automating issuance for a wildcard it how it's done. The HTTP validation process is that the cert server tells the requesting agent (some program or script) to create an uniquely named file, with some signed content, on the to-be-validated host. Then the cert server tries to access that file, and verify it's contents. If the file can be retrieved and the contents are correct, it proves that the requesting agent has the *technical* authority to control that host, and is *validated* for a cert.

If I want to get a cert for `www.example.com` the file created will be accessed with the URL of like

```
http​://www.example.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/2BHlJs9Qdk_8m6yRNzqEvwiVejyBsa8zXPpORGMIEz4
```

The file name is part of a signed block, and is unique to that request. A later request will have a new file name, with new contents, so one cannot *pre-load* the challenge response in an attempt to bypass validation. Anyway, that's all well and good for a known domain name. What happens when we try to get a cert for `*.mysub.example.com`? The cert server will attempt to access the URL of

```
http​://*.mysub.example.com/.well-known/acme-challenge/2BHlJs9Qdk_8m6yRNzqEVWiVejyBsa8zXPpORGMIEz4
```

That's not going to work. It won't even be looked up in the DNS system, not as expected anyway. Trying to look that up in DNS gets you an `NXDOMAIN` error message under normal circumstances, and when it *does* return something, it's likely not what's intended. The authentication test can't merely back down one level to `mysub.example.com` because that isn't covered by the cert requested, and may not be under the control of the requesting agent either. I may be able to create an unlimited number of subdomains for a domain, or subdomain, without the ability to add files to the parent itself.

Adding a wildcard record to the DNS actually works backwards to expectations. Such a record will *only* match when there is no matching domain in the records. If I create a subdomain of `mysub.example.com`, with the proper DNS records for it, then `*.example.com` will **not** match that. And it carries across record types too. So, a CNAME record for `mysub.example.com` without an MX record to match will still fail to match a request for an MX record using `mysub` even though there *is* a wildcard MX record. [RFC 1912](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1912) can be interesting, and convoluted, reading. {Here be dragons.}

Since a wildcard in the DNS is counter to what the wildcard in the cert means, things get even more interesting for verification. Looking at the possiblity that I could get several domains registered:

- `david.jones.name`
- `james.jones.name`
- `sarah.jones.name`
- `mary.jones.name`
- `angelica.jones.name`

I then try to get a wildcard cert for `*.jones.name`. As validation they request, say 4 domain names in the `.jones.name` namespace. I can provide any 4 of the 5 available, and meet that test. Now I have a cert for `*.jones.name`. What is Jared Jones supposed to do when he gets `jared.jones.name` and I do a MitM attack using my `*.jones.name` cert?

Due to all of this, they cannot automate verification that the request for a wildcard cert comes from a source that is responsible for *ALL* and *ANY* subdomains that might now, or *ever*, exist in that namespace. They can verify that someone has control over `sub.example.com` using automated tools, and as long as `sub` is replaced with something specific that can be validated as well. Once `sub` is replaced with `*` the tools for validation don't work. The only way to verify authority over a wildcard domain namespace is to verify ownership of the parent domain AND identity of the requesting party. If I have ownership of the parent domain `example.com` then I can freely create and control anything as a subdomain, at any level I choose. Note that here "ownership" is distinct from "control", which is what is validated by the ACME protocol.

Most often, outside of LE, a cert is obtained through the host or registrar, so the "identity" is already confirmed, and the ownership is known. If I register with GoDaddy, and host with DigitalOcean, they both "know" who I am, and have a reasonable level of confidence that I own the domain. Even if they don't issue the cert themselves, they can process the request, and verify to the CA that identity and ownership are valid. This allows the CA to issue a wildcard cert for the level requested, even if it is a level or two left of the domain I own, since the entire tree falls under my ownership.

Just looking in the whois for the domain and knowing what the rules are for that namespace is often sufficient to determine ownership. It's a human-centric process, however, and not automatable with any reasonable effort and level of reliability. To complicate things, namespace rules are, at best, inconsistent. For example, for the .name gTLD some 2nd level names are registrable, whilst others are reserved and the 3rd level names are registrable. This also applies to many ccTLDs. And some gTLDs are always 3rd level registration, `.pro` is an example, i think. How is an automated process to "know" if `*.smyther.name` is legal rather than `*.david.smyther.name`?

`smith.name` is reserved, and people have to register at the third level, so a `*.smith.name` would be a bad cert to issue. OTOH `smyther.name` is not reserved, so a `*.smyther.name` would be a good cert to issue. You can find out by using the whois system. A program would have to parse the output, which is always subject to change, hence unreliable for automation. I know about the `.name` gTLD, but I have also run across others that have weird, and changeable, rules make automation, maybe not *impossible*, but *impractical*. LE is free so they can't do every bell & whistle just because it's nice.

Again, with regard to LE issuing wildcard certs, it comes down to "automation." They 'could' build in conditionals for one case of *this*, and for another case of *that*. But where do they stop "tweeking" the rules? The more branches they build into the decision tree, the more points of failure they introduce. Because it's free and automatic, the wildcard has less value. You can get a cert that covers 100 domain names in a single shot (iirc), so why use a wildcard? Their time and effort is better spent on things with more value for the "greater good" than building exceptions and monitoring changing conditions.

Yes, I know there are use cases where a wildcard cert is indispensable. A mobile app that gets a new, random and unique subdomain on every connection couldn't use LE certs. There are limits on how many certs you can request per week, so they couldn't get a new cert every time a client connects. Technically possible, but not going to happen with LE. There are, however, other options for most of such edge cases. One of which is to buy a wildcard cert elsewhere. In many cases involving mobile apps (or even desktop applications), it's also possible to create an internal CA, and add that to the trust database of the app, then create the new short-lived certs, signed internally, as needed.

Comment: +1 thanks, this is making things make more sense. It brings up a question though: are you saying that effectively a wildcard certificate requires the same kind of verification as an EV certificate (since apparently they both need to verify your identity)?

Comment: On that I'm not sure. I have not looked into OV or EV at all. I suspect that the level of "identity" is less with wildcards. Probably enough that I control the account on the registrar that owns the domain. I.e. I control that credit card. The fact that it's maybe a fake name doesn't matter to them. I think OV might actually require a valid ID, government issued. From "in passing" reading, I think the EV actually requires paperwork and background or business report checks too. Still, I just don't know.

Comment: Ah okay, thanks a ton. I think this answer actually answers my question finally :)

Comment: This answer explains why the HTTP challenge can't work, but couldn't domain ownership be proven using the DNS challenge? https://ietf-wg-acme.github.io/acme/#rfc.section.8.5 Seems like it'd be pretty easy to use that challenge method to prove you control `jones.name` itself (and thus all subdomains).

Comment: Is `jared.smith.name` supposed to `jared.jones.name`? Otherwise, how can you do a MitM using a cert for a separate domain? (Oh, and your answer is awesome, thanks!)

Comment: At least in my experiance with wildcard certs a validation email sent to postmaster@domain.tld seemed to be all the validation the CA needed.

Comment: @PeterGreen That would make a 90 renewal period rather _non-automated_, which is contrary to one of LE's major objectives. But. see the accepted answer for how they _did_ work it out.

Answer (score -1):

This is because Let's Encrypt verifies that you own the domain before issuing a key. ***Technically, they could issues wildcard certificates, but it would be a bad idea.***

Think about it, if you worked at IBM, and you were in the accounting group, you could ask for a domain certificate issued to awesomesauce.accounting.ibm.com. But before they would issue that certificate, you would need to prove that you own that specific domain, by entering a specific DNS entry, or hosting a unique file on the webserver that proves you control it, or a few other automated ways.

## Example of why it is a bad idea.

If you asked for a wildcard certificate for *.ibm.com, how could they verify that you owned all of the subdomains? They couldnt via automated means. And if they did issue a wildcard certificate, you could use that to act as ANY subdomain on ibm.com, which could be taken advantage of. With a wildcard cert, you can act as password.ibm.com, or ad.ibm.com, or any other critical site, and decrypt the traffic of clients coming to that server.

It isn't that let's encrypt CANT issued wildcard certs, it is that it is a bad idea. They are doing amazing work at promoting HTTPS, but **issuing wildcards could lead to a lot of collateral damage.**

Comment: This doesn't make sense. Other CAs issue these just fine.

Comment: This is true, but they also require you to prove you own the domain, especially for Extended Validation.  Wildcard certificate usage is discouraged because if one was ever compromised, it could be used to impersonate any subdomain where it was valid.  It is a matter of balancing automated certificate issuance with broader security needs. It is the same reason that the certs from Let's Encrypt are only valid for 3 months. It limits damage from key compromise and encourages automation.

Comment: And other CAs are okay with wildcard non-EV certificats because they somehow do... more validation? I don't get it. You seem to be dragging topics into the discussion that don't belong in the discussion. EV is irrelevant; I'm not asking about it. Whether wildcard domains are discouraged or encouraged is besides the point. They very clearly say they **can't automate** the issuance of wildcard certs, and I'm trying to understand the reason behind that, not something else.

Comment: Wildcards certificates are NOT valid for subdomains, only for host names. (i.e. *.domain.org matches mymachine.domain.org but not www.mymachine.domain.org).

Comment: I don't fully understand your argument. You say that someone controlling awesome.accounting.ibm.com shouldn't be able to issue a wildcard certificate for *.ibm.com. I understand that, since he does not control ibm.com. But why should he not be able to issue a wildcard for *.awesome.accounting.ibm.com?

Comment: @Stephane That is correct, but deceptively so - on first read I thought it was wrong. A wildcard can cover the left-end of any FQDN, at any level. Check out Nick Craver's [blog](https://nickcraver.com/blog/2013/04/23/stackoverflow-com-the-road-to-ssl/) about converting SE to all HTTPS, where he covers the relevant RFCs. The catch is it covers only _one_ element at the level of the wildcard. The trip, for me was the use of `subdomain` and `host`. In `mymachine.domain.org` `mymachine` is _both_ a host name and a subdomain name. Within the Internet context a host is also a subdomain. [cont.]

Comment: [cont.] Though, I have to admit that it looks as if that information could be outdated. Somehow the SE sites, including their meta sites, are covered by a cert for `*.stackexchange.com`. So even though under the _one level_ rule `security.stackexchange.com` is covered and `meta.security.stackexchange.com` is not, we are running under the situation where `meta.security.stackexchange.com` **_is_** covered by `*.stackexchange.com`. I'm too lazy to chase down what has changed, or when, but the old rules seem to have been amended somewhere, somewhen.

Comment: @GypsySpellweaver Your interpretation of the subdomain and host parts only makes sense in the context of DNS, not the context of certificate validation. Having a wildcard cert for a domain does NOT allow you to use it on any subdomain as the answer suggested. Specifically, meta.security.stackexchange.com is *not* covered by the *.stackexchange.com wildcard cert. Check out section 6.4.3 and 7.2. of RFC 6125

Comment: @Stephane Actually, part of that is my error. The new URL is `security.meta.stackexchange.com`. Notice the switch from meta last to second last. Secondly, I didn't dig deep enough: the cert is for `*.stackexchange.com` but it has buried in the SAN extension `*.meta.stackexchange.com` which _does_ fit the _one level_ rule. (Thank goodness.) As to "host" vs. "subdomain", in or out of DNS a host _is_ a subdomain, while a subdomain _might_ be a host. If it is the child, at any level, of a domain, it is a subdomain. If it has an assigned IP, then it is a host. They are not mutually exclusive.

Comment: @GypsySpellweaver That distinction makes in the context of DNS but it's not relevant to cert validation or the question we're discussing (i.e. yes, you're correct but it doesn't change or even means anything regarding SSL)

Comment: Would you like to retract your arbitrary assertion that this is a "bad idea" in hindsight of the fact that they're going to start offering it pretty soon?